# Count multiple columns in a data frame in one output table

Tags: r, count, tidyverse, mutate

I have some survey data and I want to get a summary count of multiple columns.
So far I have worked out how to calculate each one individually and create a % column:

```
help_bk <- likemind %>% 
  count((help_book_1), name = "count") %>% 
  mutate((count/38)*100) %>% 
  rename("percent" = "(count/38) * 100")
help_bk
```

Which gives me this output:

[image: Output table]

I want to execute this for multiple columns in one go and get a summary table of all the variables. (Each variable has the same options 1-7 as this one)

Can anyone help enlighten me (pref in a tidyverse function)? TIA

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `across()`

```
likemind %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~list(count = count(.x),
                 percent = count/38*100)
               )
         )
```

It is hard to get an exact answer without a proper reproducible example.

Comment: I am still waiting for a proper reprex. I suspect @akrun s answer might be more accurate because there may be an issue with using `count()` inside `mutate()` here. If that is really the case, I will correct it or delete the answer

Comment: I tried the other suggestion and got this error message: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: I will make sure to post some reproducible data next time

Comment: You can still do it this time, by editing your question. This will make the question more useful for future readers and increases the chances of reversing the downvotes

Answer (score 1):

We may loop over the column names of interest, get the `count` and store it in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nm1 <- names(likemind)[1:5] # for the first five columns in the dataset
lst1 <- map(nm1, ~ 
    likemind %>% 
      select(all_of(.x)) %>%
      count(across(1), name = "count") %>% 
     mutate((count/38)*100) %>% 
     rename("percent" = "(count/38) * 100")
    )
```